# Toggle "active" in DOM Nodelist after user clicks anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript

I have a circular menu at the bottom right corner of the page, that a user can toggle open and close. I want to implement a clever way to ensure that if a user opens the menu, and then clicks away anywhere on the page, then the menu will close. Here's what I have so far:

```
1    // on page load
2    document.addEventListener("click", () => {
3      const menu = document.getElementById("circularMenu");
4
5      if (menu.classList.contains("active")) {
6        document.getElementById("circularMenu1").classList.toggle("active");
7      }
8    });
```

The problem with this code is that the menu never opens when the user clicks on it, as line 6 gets invoked immediately (ie once the user clicks on the menu to open it, this event listener closes it). I've tried doing `document.body` instead of the whole document, but the problem with that, is the code gets invoked only when text or my navbar is pressed -- not exactly what I'm looking for, I want the event listener to be hooked onto anywhere on the page.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that this is a React project. TIA.

Edit:

Got it to work as needed with

```
      if (
        e.target.classList.value !== "floating-btn" &&
        e.target.classList.value !== "fa fa-bars"
      ) {
        document.getElementById("circularMenu").classList.remove("active");
      }
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener('click',function(e){ if(e.target && e.target.id == 'yourMenuId'){ //keep active } else { //close it }` - Just a quick idea I had in mind. Though you'll probably have to add extra conditionals for element ids inside the menu

Comment: What does "closed" mean? Toggling a class _just_ toggles a class, it does not change focus, so what else are you relying on? Which leads us to: please form a [mcve] here, both to help us understand what you're really doing, but more importantly, for you to reduce your problem to literally the bare minimum so that it becomes so obvious what's going on that 99% of the time you realise the obvious part without even needing to post to SO.

Comment: Presence of "Active" class means open. The absence of `active` means closed.

Comment: @icecub I'll try this out

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. The only way it will close is if I click anywhere on the page -- it won't close if I click on the button itself.

Comment: toggling a class on one DOM elements does not remove classes from another, so now you have two elements with `active`: what does your CSS do in this case? (which brings us to "please show a [mcve] again")

Comment: the explanation of your problem is really obscure. From what I understand is that in any case your approach is bad and that the use of a JS toggle cannot solve this problem

Comment: I've made an edit to the question. Thank you @icecub.

Comment: it's always obscure. a clearer example is needed

Comment: You're welcome. Since, as @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans suggested, this question lacks a mcve, I will not turn it into an answer. I suggest editing your question in such a way that it is, so it becomes a useful question for future visitors that have the same (or a similar) question. I will gladly turn my comment into an answer after that :)

Comment: Why are you using `.value` in your edit? `classList` has a `.contains()` for this purpose, because there is no guarantee your own code or even third party code doesn't add extra general purposes class names.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question, here is my solution:

(and this is **a minimal reproducible example** , *as asked before*)

```js
document.documentElement.onclick=e=>
  {
    let current = document.querySelector('.active')
      ;
    if ( e.target.classList.contains('menu') )
      {
      //  e.preventDefault()
      if (e.target === current) { e.target.classList.remove('active')  }
      else
        {
        if (current) { current.classList.remove('active') }
        e.target.classList.add('active') 
        }
      }
    else if (current) { current.classList.remove('active') }
  }
```

```css
.menu { 
  display: inline-block;
  border:3px solid grey;
  margin-right: 3em;
  padding: .2em .4em;
}
.active {
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="menu">menu 1</a>
<a href="#" class="menu">menu 2</a>
<a href="#" class="menu">menu 3</a>
<a href="#" class="menu">menu 4</a>

<p>something else</p>
```